# How to update custom fields when post is published?

Tags: php, custom-field, post-meta

I've created two custom fields on the post edit screen using the ACF Pro plugin. If the fields are empty, I want to set the current user as both the field's value when the user clicks Publish button.

This is how I'm calling the function

```
add_action('transition_post_status', [$this, 'setOwnerAssignee'], 10, 3);
```

This is the `setOwnerAssignee` function

```
public function setOwnerAssignee($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    if ($new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'post') {
        $current_user = strval(get_current_user_id());
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'owner', $current_user, '');
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'assigned', $current_user, '');
        // wp_die('die');
    }
}
```

I checked in PHPMyAdmin and the function properly sets the values if I use the `wp_die` in the end or if I remove the if condition. But it isn't working without that.

I'm fairly new to WordPress development so I might be doing something silly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to change your action to `publish_post`.

`publish_post` only fires when a post is published.
The callback function will only receive only one argument, the post id, with it you can do all your needed checks and update the meta as needed.

By the way, update post meta doesn't play well with ACF in the initial update. If meta field was empty it will sometimes not update it.

Acf has its own function to deal with meta updates [update_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/), better use it instead.